# Pandas Python Regular Expression Assistance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wasn't sure what to call this title, feel free to edit it if you think there is a better name.

What I am trying to do is find cases that match certain search criteria.

Specifically, I am trying to find sentences that contain the word "where" in them. Once I have identified that, I am trying to find cases where the word "SQL" command is also located within that same tag.

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

search_criteria = ['where']

```
df4

         Q      R
0    file.sql  <sentence>dave likes stuff</sentence><properties>version = "2", description = "example" type="SqlCommand">select id, name, from table where criteria = '5'</property><sentence>dave hates stuff>

0    file.sql  <sentence>dave likes stuff</sentence><properties>version = "2", description = "example">select id, name, from table where criteria = '5'</properties><sentence>dave hates stuff>
```

I am trying to return this:

```
         Q      R
0    file.sql   <properties>version = "2", description = "example">select id, name, from table</properties>
```

This record should get returned because it contains both "where" and "sqlcommand".

Here is my current process:

```
regex_stuff =  df_all_xml_mfiles_tgther[cc:cc+1].R.str.findall('(<[^<]*?' + 'where' + '[^>]*?>)', re.IGNORECASE)


sql_command_regex_stuff = df_all_xml_mfiles_tgther[cc:cc+1].R.str.findall('(<property[^<]*?' + 'sqlcommand' + '[^>]*?<\/property>)', re.IGNORECASE)


if not regex_stuff.empty: #if one of the search criteria is found

    if not sql_command_regex_stuff.empty: #check to see if the phrase "sqlcommand" is found anywhere as well

          (insert rest of code)
```

This does not return anything.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1:**

It seems like I need to do something at the end, to make the regex look something like this:

```
   <property[^<]*?SqlCommand[^(<\/property>)]*
```

I feel like this is the right direction, doesn't work, but I feel like this is the right step.

Comment: You are trying to find lines that _literally_ contain the word 'sqlcommand'. Is it your intention?

Comment: yes, also, I clarified my first post

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter with `str.contains`:

```
df[(df['R'].str.contains('where', flags=re.IGNORECASE) & df['R'].str.contains('sqlcommand', flags=re.IGNORECASE))]

    Q             R
0   file.sql    <sentence>dave likes stuff</sentence><properti...
```

or use `~` to return the opposite: strings that do not contain 'sqlcommand' or 'where'

```
df[~(df['R'].str.contains('where', flags=re.IGNORECASE) & df['R'].str.contains('sqlcommand', flags=re.IGNORECASE))]

    Q            R
1   file.sql    <sentence>dave likes stuff</sentence><properti...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to have proper XML and SQL content, so you should
make the following corrections:

1. As the opening tag is `<properties>`, the closing tag must also be 
   `</properties>`, not `</property>`.
2. `version`, `description` and `type` are **attributes** (after them
   there is `>` closing the opening tag, so after `properties` there
   should be a **space**, not `>`.
3. Remove `,` after `version="2"`.
4. Remove `,` after `name`.
5. Remove `(` before `<properties` and `)` after `</properties>`.

To find the required rows, use `str.contains` as the filtering
expression.

Below you have an example program:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df4 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Q' : 'file.sql',
  'R' : [
    '<s>dave</s><properties type="SqlCommand">select id, name '
      'from table where criteria=\'5\'</properties><s>dave</s>',
    '<s>dave</s><properties>select id, name from table '
      'where criteria=\'6\'</properties><s>dave</s>',
    '<s>mike</s><properties type="SqlCommand">drop table "Xyz"'
      '</properties><s>mike</s>' ]})
df5 = df4[df4.R.str.contains(
    '<properties[^<>]+?sqlcommand[^<>]+?>[^<>]+?where',
    flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
print(df5)
```

Note that the regex takes care about the proper sequence of
strings:

- First match `<properties`.
- Then a sequence of chars other than `<` and `>` (`[^<>]+?`).
  so we are still within the just opened XML tag.
- Then match `sqlcommand` (ignoring case).
- Then another sequence of chars other than `<` and `>`
  (`[^<>]+?`).
- Then `>`, closing the tag.
- Then another sequence of chars other than `<` and `>`
  (`[^<>]+?`).
- And finally `where` (also ignoring case).

An attempt to check for `sqlcommand` and `where` in two separate
regexes is wrong, as these words can be at other locations,
which do not meet your requirement.

Comment: I cannot remove the commas. That is how it shows up. I imported an SSIS file as text to do some manipulation and then used a join to put everything on one line.

Comment: OK, initially I thought you should have **proper SQL** and **proper XML**. If this is not the case (your text is "something similiar to SQL" and "something similiar to XML") omit some corrections.